# Rstudio cannot show the running result in the console

Tags: xcode, performance, console, rstudio, environment

As can be seen in the picture, when I run the code, the result in the console part shows the same code as the same as I input in the upside rather than the result, so I wonder what is wrong with my manipulate?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing the rest of the code you've entered into the console, but it looks like you are just defining a function, not actually calling the function. If you call the function it should execute and show results in the console.

Comment: after  I run the code the result is still the same, I don't know whether it is the thing that you mean" calling the funtion"?

Comment: The code you're running is all within a function definition block (i.e. between `{}` after a function() call). None of that code will actually execute when you define the function. If you aren't familiar with R functions [check out this tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/functions-in-r-a-tutorial)

Comment: yes，I know the reason now ,thank you for your sharing.